# Не работает поиск, по списку, перенесенный из си. В чем различия работы обеих функций?

Tags: c#, c

В модуле `libavi_plugin` из состава `VLC`, присутствует следующий поиск по списку чанков:

```
void *AVI_ChunkFind_( avi_chunk_t *p_chk,
                      vlc_fourcc_t i_fourcc, int i_number, bool b_list )
{
    if( !p_chk )
        return NULL;

    for( avi_chunk_t *p_child = p_chk->common.p_first;
                      p_child; p_child = p_child->common.p_next )
    {
        if( b_list && p_child->list.i_type == 0 )
            continue;

        if( p_child->common.i_chunk_fourcc != i_fourcc &&
            (!b_list || p_child->list.i_type != i_fourcc) )
            continue;

        if( i_number-- == 0 )
            return p_child; /* We found it */
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

И я его перевел на [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), мало изменений, т.к. работаю через неуправляемую память:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct AviChunkCommon
{
    public Fcc ChunkFcc;
    public ulong Size;
    public ulong Position;

    public AviChunk* Next;
    public AviChunk* Father;
    public AviChunk* First;
}
```

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct AviChunk
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public AviChunkCommon Common;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public AviChunkList List;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public AviChunkIdx1 Idx1;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public AviChunkAvih Avih;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public AviChunkStrh Strh;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public AviChunkStrf Strf;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public AviChunkStrd Strd;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public AviChunkVprp Vprp;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public AviChunkIndx Index;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public AviChunkString String;

    public ulong Size => ((Common.Size + 1u) & ~1u) + 8;
    public ulong End => Common.Position + Size;
}
```

```
private static AviChunk* ChunkFind(AviChunk* chunk, Fcc fcc, int number, bool list)
{
    if (chunk == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    for (AviChunk* pChild = chunk->Common.First;
                   pChild != null; pChild = pChild->Common.Next)
    {
        if (list && pChild->List.Type == 0u)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (pChild->Common.ChunkFcc != fcc &&
              (!list || pChild->List.Type != fcc))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if ((--number) == 0) // We found it!
        {
            return pChild;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Но этот поиск на `c#`, ведет себя не так как на си. Если необходимый элемент находится в `chunk`, то он его находит, но если он находится глубже, то не не найдет.

Подскажите в чем различие работы кода на `c#` и почему он ведет себя не так как я предполагаю?

При этом, я уверен в том что там есть необходимые данные, вот дамп списка:

```
* LIST-root size: 810026560 pos: 0
    + RIFF-AVI  size: 810026552 pos: 0
        + LIST-hdrl size: 8898 pos: 12
            + avih size: 56 pos: 24
            + LIST-strl size: 4316 pos: 88
                + strh size: 56 pos: 100
            + JUNK size: 4116 pos: 212
            + vprp size: 68 pos: 4336
            + LIST-strl size: 4230 pos: 4412
            + strh size: 56 pos: 4424
        + JUNK size: 4116 pos: 4526
        + JUNK size: 260 pos: 8650
        + LIST-INFO size: 34 pos: 8918
        + ISFT size: 22 pos: 8930
        + JUNK size: 1016 pos: 8960
        + LIST-movi size: 802487072 pos: 9984
        + idx1 size: 7529488 pos: 802497064
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ошибка

> if ((--number) == 0) // We found it!

исходный код

> ```
> if( i_number-- == 0 )
>       return p_child; /* We found it */
> ```

читается так

```
int tmp = i_number;
i_number = i_number - 1;
if (tmp == 0)
  return p_child; /* We found it */
```

А вы зачем-то суффиксный декремент заменили префиксным и получили

```
i_number = i_number - 1;
if (i_number == 0)
  return p_child; /* We found it */
```

Comment: Да... А я не подумал об этом. Теперь находит. Спасибо!